# How to used sorted() to sort data by certain attributes in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
fballsorted = sorted(sightings_us, key = lambda x: x["duration (seconds)"], reverse=True)
print(fballsorted["datetime"], fballsorted["duration (seconds)"])
```

Above is the command that I want to sort data accordingly based on duration attribute but
Im getting error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn5ou.png)

I still new on python jupyter notebook usage but im not understanding the problem. Does it mean data type for "duration" attribute is wrong but im check it still on integer or number form in raw file. Can anyone help this problem.

Comment: were you able to get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

After using `sorted()` on `sightings_us`, `fballsorted` becomes a list.
The return type of `sorted()` function is a list.

You can print `fballsorted` and see.

If you want to extract the elements of `fballsorted` you need slicing with integer values not strings.